# how can I allow access to only one URL from a docker container

Tags: docker

I would like to only permit outgoing http requests to a specified url from a particular docker container. Is there a relatively painless way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  The only* way to implement this sort of per-URL restriction is if all requests were made through a proxy, so you would need to (a) set up a proxy, (b) configure the rules appropriately, (c) arrange for tools inside your container to use the proxy and (d) ensure that your container has no other outbound access.

So, maybe that would like...

- Create a proxy container on the default network
- Create an isolated internal network (`docker network create --isolated mynetwork`)
- Attach the isolated network to the proxy container (`docker network connect...`)
- Create your application container on the isolated network (`docker run --net=mynetwork...`)

I would not describe that as "relatively painless".

*Well, you might able to hack something together using iptables and string-matching inside packets, but just saying that makes me feel unclean.